# Service account created from a sink cannot be found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm creating a sink by running the following command (as an organization administrator):

```
gcloud logging sinks create vpc_flow_sink storage.googleapis.com/<storage_bucket_name> --include-children --organization=<organization_id> --log-filter="resource.type="gce_subnetwork" AND logName:"logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fvpc_flows""
```

The command executes successfully and outputs the following text:

```
Created [https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/organizations/<organization_id>/sinks/<sink_name>].
Please remember to grant serviceAccount:o<organization_id>-511237@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com the Storage Object Creator role on the bucket.
```

However, when I go to actually apply the permission to the storage bucket, I cannot find this account (in either the project or within the organization). The accounts also do not appear when I run:

```
gcloud organizations get-iam-policy <organization_id>
```

When I describe the sink, the service account exists within the writerIdentity field:

```
gcloud beta logging sinks describe vpc_flow_sink --organization <organization_id>
...
writerIdentity: serviceAccount:o<organization_id>-511237@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
...
```

For reference, to try debug this issue, I've attached the following roles: Organization Role Administrator, Logging Admin, Owner, Project Owner, Organization Administrator, Storage Admin.

I am genuinely lost on what to do, how do I go about granting the bucket the role to this account?

Comment: 1/2) I am not sure in your case but here are some tips. Service Accounts exist in their own section of the Google Cloud Console. Once you grant them permissions manually in the IAM section, they will appear. Service Accounts can exist at the Project, Folder or Organization level. In your case, you will probably find the Service Account under Service Accounts at the Organization level. Log in to the Google Cloud Console. Go to IAM. Near the top next to "Google Cloud Platform" you will see your Project ID. Click the down arrow and select your Organization (it has the building icon).

Comment: 2/2) If you do not see your service account in the IAM section, click the "ADD" button. Add the service account using the email address displayed in your question. Then grant the policies you require. NOTE: to correct my previous comment. "Service Account can have roles assigned at the Project, Folder or Organization level and a combination of those levels".

Comment: I don't believe that service accounts can be viewed in the console at the org level. 
Google states that, "Page not viewable for organizations. To view this page, select a project."

Comment: @Robert any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 2):

When applying the permission to you export destination, don't copy:

`serviceAccount:o<organization_id>-511237@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

but instead just use everything after `serviceAccount:`

`o<organization_id>-511237@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com`...

Google will then recognize the service account. However, I still cannot detect it via `gcloud organizations get-iam-policy <organization_id>`

Comment: You are my hero, this totally worked!

Answer (score 0):

As some are facing challenge to locate the `Service Account`

Please find it at `Bucket Details` --> `Permissions Tab` --> 'View By Principals'

[image]